# Return list in every possible ordered/sorted combination

Tags: c#, asp.net

How would I be able to return this list in every possible ordered combination?
I have this list, and wanted to return a new list sorted in a different possibility, like `1,2,3,4`, `2,3,1,4`, etc (all possibilities)

```
 var list = new List<string>();
 list.Add("1");
 list.Add("2");
 list.Add("3");
 list.Add("4");
```

How is this done?

Comment: This kind of question isn't appropriate for Stack Overflow -- we're not here to write code for you. If you're having a specific problem writing the code yourself, feel free to ask a question to get unstuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the following [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43767/A-C-List-Permutation-Iterator) on CodeProject regarding a list permutation iterator:

```
public static IEnumerable<IList> Permutate(IList sequence, int count)
{
    if (count == 1) yield return sequence;
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            foreach (var perm in Permutate(sequence, count - 1))
                yield return perm;
            RotateRight(sequence, count);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the method like this:

```
var listPermutated = Permutate(list, list.Count);
```